# How to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)=\mathbb{P}(X=\frac{a}{Y})$, when $X$ or $Y$ take multiple values?

Tags: random-variable, discrete-data

Assume $X,Y$ are discrete and have a finite outcome space.

How to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)=\mathbb{P}(X=\frac{a}{Y})$, when $X$ or $Y$ take multple values?

Does one write out the result for each output value that $X,Y$ take?

Thus, if $Y \in \{0,1\}$, then

$$\mathbb{P}(XY=a)$$  $$= \mathbb{P}(X=\frac{a}{0}) \text{ or }\mathbb{P}(X=a) $$

out of which the first is undef.

I.e.

$$= \mathbb{P}(X=a) $$

If $Y \in \{0,1,2\}$, then

$$\mathbb{P}(XY=a)= \mathbb{P}(X=a) \text{ or } \mathbb{P}(X=a/2) $$

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ continuous or discrete variables? Is the set of possible values for each finite?

Comment: $P(XY=a)$ _does not_ equal $P(X=\frac aY)$ when $Y=0$; just because you are using probability does not mean you are allowed to divide by $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For discrete and finite $X$ and $Y$ you could say

$$\mathbb{P}(XY=a)= \begin{cases} \mathbb{P}(X=a/Y) &\quad \text{if $a \neq 0$}\\
\mathbb{P}(X=0 \lor Y=0) &\quad \text{if $a = 0$} \end{cases}$$

Comment: My question didn't particularly concern $a$, but $X,Y$. So could assume $a$ fixed.

Comment: @mavavilj you can replace the condition $a=0$ by $X=0 \lor Y=0$. It just shows that the case $a=0$ (which implies  $X=0 \lor Y=0$)  is special. When $Y$ is never 0 then $\mathbb{P}(X=0 \lor Y=0) = \mathbb{P}(X=0)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is use the law of iterated expectation, that is
$P(XY=a)=E[P(XY=a|Y)]$, where the expectation is taken over all values of $Y$. This works in the discrete and continuous case. In the discrete case you can write the resulting integral as $P(XY=a)=E[P(XY=a|Y)]=\sum_y P(X=a/y)P(Y=y)$, where the sum is taken over all values that $Y$ takes.